# angularjs if container width less than ul element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have dynamic bread crumbs data. which I'm binding in DOM with ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="breadCrumb in breadCrumbs">
        <a  href="javascript:void(0);">{{ breadCrumb.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to calculate in every repeat ul width and compare with container's width. If container width is less than ul width, I want to add all previous li elements hide class.

for example:

```
[{name:'home'},{name:'movies'},{name:'Comedy'},{name:'The hangover'}]
```

Assume, that I have this data and after second object, there is not space in container. Application must generate such html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-item HIDE" ng-repeat="breadCrumb in breadCrumbs">
        <a  href="javascript:void(0);">home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item HIDE" ng-repeat="breadCrumb in breadCrumbs">
        <a  href="javascript:void(0);">movies</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="breadCrumb in breadCrumbs">
        <a  href="javascript:void(0);">Comedy</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="breadCrumb in breadCrumbs">
        <a  href="javascript:void(0);">The hangover</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've made it without angular, but I want to try it with angular.
How it will be possible in angular way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create a custom filter which reduces your breadcrumb list based on the desired width.

```
<span 
  ng-repeat="breadCrumb in breadCrumbs | crumbFilter: iWidth ">
  &#8594;
  <a  href="javascript:void(0);">{{ breadCrumb.name }}</a>
</span>
```

**Custom filter**

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('crumbFilter', function() {
  return function(list,width) {
    var testString = "";
    var filteredList = [];
    var i = list.length-1;
    while (i>=0 && testString.length<width) {
      testString += "  "+list[i].name;
      filteredList.unshift(list[i]);
      i--;
    }
    return filteredList;
  }
});
```

The [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzojc4h0/)